# Error when publishing something with ninject?

Tags: azure, publish

I'm getting an error when i publish my website to azure. I don't get any errors when i run my site on localhost.

This is the error i get. I'm having troubles to find out whats really wrong. 
Please help me to push me in the right direction to solve this error.

thanks!
[image]

Comment: Not enough information to answer your question. Show us registration code, show us `global.asax.cs`

Answer (score 0):

It could be many things. Are you loading your ninject container configuration from an external file? If so, is this file being deployed to Azure? That could explain why it works locally, but not in the cloud.